# What happened to the site proposal on Area51 for HomeImprovement?

Tags: discussion

All the example good/bad questions are no longer displayed. The FAQ is also a little sparse on details of what questions would be considered on or off topic.

Is there any way to go back and look at the full site proposal after it goes into beta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. At the top right of the site page on Area51, click on the 'Definition' tab.

Comment: Thanks. I just missed it. They shouldn't hide that right in front of my face like that!

Comment: Yeah, it took me a while to find it during the commitment phase, even with my obsessive checking the percent 'til beta.